# Reset randomization after it goes through all the items in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm learning JS and I just finished a project, here the code:

```js
const menu = {
    _meal: "",
    _price: 0,
    //Let set the new value of meal only if it's a string.
    set meal(mealToCheck) {
        if (typeof mealToCheck === "string") {
            return this._meal = mealToCheck;
        }
    },
    //Let set the new value of price only if it's a number.
    set price(priceToCheck) {
        if (typeof priceToCheck === "number") {
            return this._price = priceToCheck;
        }
    },
    //If both setters are true, then return a message using them, otherwise return message saying the values are wrong.
    get todaysSpecial() {
        if (this._meal && this._price) {
            return `Today's Special is ${this._meal}, for just ${this._price}£!!`;
        } else {
            return "Meal and Price wasn't entered correctly!!";
        }
    }
};

//Arrays for the meal options and respective prices, also a constant to get a random number in the array range.
const meals = ["Pizza", "Steak", "Pie", "Roast", "Moussaka", "Lasagne", "Tacos"];
const prices = [/*Pizza*/9, /*Steak*/13, /*Pie*/11, /*Roast*/14, /*Moussaka*/9, /*Lasagne*/10, /*Tacos*/9];
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * meals.length);

//Assigns a new random value from the arrays. I used a single randomizer so that you can combine a plate to its price by the index number.
menu.meal = meals[random];
menu.price = prices[random];

//Check if the number of items in the meals and prices array it's equal, and if it is, creates the menu of the day string.
if (meals.length === prices.length) {
    console.log(menu.todaysSpecial);
} else {
    console.log("The number of prices and meals don't match!!");
}
```

At the end of the code I added a couple of arrays and a `Math.random` so that every time I run it, it gives me a different value.

Now I'm trying to find a way to have the random value give unique values until it reaches the array length, and then restart. At the moment I have 7 items in the array simulating the day of the week, I'd like to have each item coming out once per week and then reset.

I know how to do it by following the array index order, but I can't come out with a way to do it randomly, any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your prices and meals array to make it a bit simpler, then shuffle it.

```
const menu = {
  _meal: "",
  _price: 0,
  //Let set the new value of meal only if it's a string.
  set meal(mealToCheck) {
    if (typeof mealToCheck === "string") {
      return (this._meal = mealToCheck);
    }
  },
  //Let set the new value of price only if it's a number.
  set price(priceToCheck) {
    if (typeof priceToCheck === "number") {
      return (this._price = priceToCheck);
    }
  },
  //If both setters are true, then return a message using them, otherwise return message saying the values are wrong.
  get todaysSpecial() {
    if (this._meal && this._price) {
      return `Today's Special is ${this._meal}, for just ${this._price}£!!`;
    } else {
      return "Meal and Price wasn't entered correctly!!";
    }
  }
};

//Arrays for the meal options and respective prices, also a constant to get a random number in the array range.
let meals = [
  { name: "Pizza", price: 9 },
  { name: "Steak", price: 13 },
  { name: "Pie", price: 11 },
  { name: "Roast", price: 14 },
  { name: "Moussaka", price: 9 },
  { name: "Lasagne", price: 10 },
  { name: "Tacos", price: 9 }
];

// Used to shuffle your meals array
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle.
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    // Pick a remaining element.
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex],
      array[currentIndex]
    ];
  }

  return array;
}

meals = shuffle(meals);

// Iterate meals
for (let i = 0; i < meals.length; i++) {
  menu.meal = meals[i].name;
  menu.price = meals[i].price;
  console.log(menu.todaysSpecial);
}
```

Comment: I just tried the code you posted, but it gives me as result all the entries from the meals array, not just the one picked, I'm trying to go through if I can spot why.

Comment: What I was looking for was a way to have a single day printed, not all, but after thinking through it, I actually think your way it's better

Answer (score 0):

It is easy every time you pick value from the array remove it and when the array end just reset the array to the initial value
For not having probleme with rand nomber it should be like this
`Rand=Math.random()*array.lenght`;

Comment: Yes but that's the part I know already, I understand that to avoid picking the item again I need to remove it, but how? I've been able to actually remove it temporarily, but as soon as I run again, it will start with a full array and remove the one just picked, so I basically have always 6 items instead of 7. As for the "Math.random" using "array.length" I knew already, it's is there in the code already.

Comment: It is because your declaring your var in the function the array need to be in the top level of the script

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. Instead of creating a new function, I changed the  todaysSpecial function to take in array, and randomly select an element from array.

```
const menu = {
  _meal: '',
  _price: 0,
  set meal (mealToCheck) {
    if(mealToCheck.length >= 1) {
    return this._meal= mealToCheck
    }
  },
  set price (priceToCheck ) {
    return this._price = priceToCheck  
  },
  get todaysSpecial () {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this._meal.length);
    if(this._meal && this._price) {
    return `Today’s Special is ${this._meal[random]} for $${this._price[random]}!`
    } else {
    return `Meal or price was not set correctly!`
    }
   },
 };

 menu.meal= ['Burger', 'pizza', 'steak', 'seafood boil'];
 menu.price= [15, 5, 30, 40];

 console.log(menu.todaysSpecial)
```